# Accumulation of union of sets

Tags: alloy

I have two classes `A` and `B` and a relation with extra data of class `R` on them.

So, `A` and `B` are related to each other via `R`.

```
sig A {}
sig B {}

sig R {
    a : A,
    b : B,
    data : Bool
}
```

here, Bool is defined as:

```
sig Bool {}
sig True, False extends Bool {}
```

Now, I extend `A` like this:

```
sig A{
    allb : some B
}
```

Which contains all instances of `B` for which there is a relation between this `A` and that `B` and where the data is of type `True`.

I want to express the following logical statement as an Alloy fact:

[image: Formal version of text above]
<sub>(source: [dropproxy.com](http://dropproxy.com/f/3B))</sub>

I assume here that `True == 1` and `False != 1` and that the sets `A` and `R` contain all instances of `A` and `R` respectively.

What I've tried so far is to define a `fun trueR(a : A)` which should return all `R`'s for which `R.a = a and r.data = True` and a `fact allbIsRTrue` which states that for each `A` `allb` should be the sum of the `R.b`'s returned by `trueR`.

However, here is where I get stuck, I can't find the right construct to sum over sets in the reference and tries with `sum` have resulted in syntax errors.

How would I specify my formal constraint as an Alloy fact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to use set comprehension.  In Alloy, this is the syntax for set comprehension

```
{x: X | f(x)}
```

The expression above evaluates to a set of `X`'s for which `f(x)` holds.

In your example, to express the fact for `allB` you can write something like

```
fact fAllB {
    all a: A | 
        a.allB = {b: B | 
            some r: R | r.ra = a and r.rb = b and r.data = True}
}
```

In English, this fact reads "for all `a` of set `A`, `a.allB` is a set of all `B`'s such that there exist some `r` which "connects" those exact `a` and `b` and for which `r.data` is `True`.

Note the following modifications I made to the rest of your model:

- I made the `Bool` sig abstract because you probably don't want bools that are neither `True` nor `False`
- I made the `True` and `False` sigs singleton sigs (i.e., `one sig`) because you probably want to have exactly one atom of each of them
- I renamed relations `a` and `b` to `ra` and `rb` to avoid name aliasing and potential confusion

Here is the rest of your model that I used for this example

```
abstract sig Bool {}
one sig True, False extends Bool {}

sig A {
  allB: set B
} 
sig B {}
sig R {
  ra : A,
  rb : B,
  data : Bool
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that detailed description and the suggestions for the boolean type!